# small server, recommended os

Tags: linux, vps, memory

I have a small VPS (256mb ram/512mb burst). I am in confusion as to which linux should i install on it, choice being, Ubuntu or CentOS.

The server is going to be used for a rails app. and will also need, ffmpeg, memcached, beanstalkd, nginx, imagemagik.

Regards

Comment: Don't forget to pick an answer if we've answered your question! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any answer you'll get here is purely anecdotal. I prefer Debian or Ubuntu. Make sure you don't use the 64 bit version if you're using less than 4Gb of ram. Also, check out [Linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=c76fb744149d3f658d38406bb2606bb783bf3d23) for a better deal(assuming you're using Slicehost).

Comment: i am on 123systems.net

Comment: They have a pretty shoddy record. You're going to run into MAJOR I/O bottlenecks.

Comment: yeah i know... i am there to have the site up... once its up, i plan to move to linode...

Answer (score 0):

Are those the only two choices?  For that size, you may want to consider Debian.  Ubuntu is based on it, but Debian is much lighter.

Comment: available choices are arch, suse, debian, fedora, ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Either choice will suit you well- do you know what versions of either they will install? That might affect your decision.

Comment: i have nearly all versions of ubuntu from 8.04 and centos 5

Comment: if you check here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29#Releases
you can see the currently supported releases :)

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at rPath and Stacklet (http://stacklet.com/)